# How can I successfully install eclipsefp dependencies? (buildwrapper and scion-browser)

Tags: haskell, debian-based

I have been for a long time to successfully install the eclipse eclipse "fp" extension that I want to try even knowing that is not maintained. I tried old proposed solutions, which do not resolved my issue, but at least helped. There's a question that a user suggests making a sandbox "as the author suggests", but it is offline, I have no clue how to do it in the context of the Eclipse FP installation.

Firstly. Having a fresh install with the cabal executable and ghc in my path, going to Haskell's options in the eclipse preferences gave errors related to UI, so I began installing the dependencies mentioned in the online [page](http://eclipsefp.github.io/).

To install the dependencies at once, I finally executed `cabal install utf8-string-0.3.8  happy terminfo  buildwrapper  scion-browser-0.3.2` using ghc-7.8.4 (deb 9) which did not led me again a error related to dependencies in contrary to other versions (maybe all of the debian repo). But gave me the following error:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring th-lift-instances-0.1.11...
Configuring happy-1.19.5...
Building th-lift-instances-0.1.11...
Failed to install th-lift-instances-0.1.11
Build log ( /home/user/.cabal/logs/ghc-7.8.4/th-lift-instances-0.1.11-CIJlvzaRbR2DTAkKUXtGrB.log ):
cabal: Entering directory '/tmp/cabal-tmp-13572/th-lift-instances-0.1.11'
Configuring th-lift-instances-0.1.11...
Preprocessing library for th-lift-instances-0.1.11..
Building library for th-lift-instances-0.1.11..
[1 of 1] Compiling Instances.TH.Lift ( src/Instances/TH/Lift.hs, dist/build/Instances/TH/Lift.o )
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
integer-gmp base transformers-0.3.0.0 fail-4.9.0.0 ... linking ... done primitive-0.7.0.0 array-0.5.0.0 deepseq-1.3.0.2 ... linking ... done.
[...]

src/Instances/TH/Lift.hs:141:10:
    Duplicate instance declarations:
      instance Lift Text.Text
        -- Defined at src/Instances/TH/Lift.hs:141:10
      instance Lift Text.Text -- Defined in ‘Data.Text’

src/Instances/TH/Lift.hs:144:10:
    Duplicate instance declarations:
      instance Lift Text.Lazy.Text
        -- Defined at src/Instances/TH/Lift.hs:144:10
      instance Lift Text.Lazy.Text -- Defined in ‘Data.Text.Lazy’
cabal: Leaving directory '/tmp/cabal-tmp-13572/th-lift-instances-0.1.11'
Building happy-1.19.5...
Installed happy-1.19.5
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
http-api-data-0.3.6-GIzTiZjkgryH72JVZRYNGw depends on http-api-data-0.3.6
which failed to install.
persistent-2.7.3.1-3HvNd9Eyn968ranIeThmQz depends on persistent-2.7.3.1 which
failed to install.
persistent-sqlite-2.6.4-EE5sqx4PH2C9q8mniK9twF depends on
persistent-sqlite-2.6.4 which failed to install.
persistent-template-2.1.3.6-BjKjksCBzOLEjWTgFDeWyM depends on
persistent-template-2.1.3.6 which failed to install.
scion-browser-0.3.2-KA6F1jz9d5G2f7dPj11jrk depends on scion-browser-0.3.2
which failed to install.
th-lift-instances-0.1.11-CIJlvzaRbR2DTAkKUXtGrB failed during the building
phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
uri-bytestring-0.3.0.2-5kqtjrq6OAQHifT5lZcXoC depends on
uri-bytestring-0.3.0.2 which failed to install.
```

Output near the error with "-v" option:

```
Installed happy-1.19.5
World file is already up to date.
The executable file
has been installed at /home/user/.cabal/bin/happy
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  die', called at ./Distribution/Client/Install.hs:993:15 in main:Distribution.Client.Install
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
http-api-data-0.3.6-GIzTiZjkgryH72JVZRYNGw depends on http-api-data-0.3.6
which failed to install.
persistent-2.7.3.1-3HvNd9Eyn968ranIeThmQz depends on persistent-2.7.3.1 which
failed to install.
persistent-sqlite-2.6.4-EE5sqx4PH2C9q8mniK9twF depends on
persistent-sqlite-2.6.4 which failed to install.
persistent-template-2.1.3.6-BjKjksCBzOLEjWTgFDeWyM depends on
persistent-template-2.1.3.6 which failed to install.
scion-browser-0.3.2-KA6F1jz9d5G2f7dPj11jrk depends on scion-browser-0.3.2
which failed to install.
th-lift-instances-0.1.11-CIJlvzaRbR2DTAkKUXtGrB failed during the building
phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
uri-bytestring-0.3.0.2-5kqtjrq6OAQHifT5lZcXoC depends on
uri-bytestring-0.3.0.2 which failed to install.
```

I know the plugin is not maintained, but still I would like to try,

Comment: Are you sure you want to use such ancient technology?

Comment: I guess now I'm pretty sure I don't want to use any more old software without knowing exactly what I'm trying to do. Especially in this language.

Comment: It looks like the dependency bounds in the problematic version of `th-lift-instances` have been fixed: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/th-lift-instances-0.1.11/revisions/

Answer (score 0):

I found this [plugin](https://github.com/rikvdkleij/intellij-haskell) in Haskell IDE's [recommendations](https://wiki.haskell.org/IDEs). It's awesome, I can load my project in GHCi or run it in one click. I wish I tried this before.

I was definitely trying to do something wrong, deprecated software is bad idea, and generally not a good practice at all (stubbornness has to pass at some point).